# Untoggle action resets checkboxes inside a <p:rowExpansion>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the datatable inside the rowExpansion and I can select rows of that table by means of checkboxes. I select some of them. But after I click on the row-toggler icon to untoggle inner table the event resets checkboxes in "false".
Can I avoid this behavior ?

Car Brand:

```
import java.util.List;

public class CarBrand {

    private final String brandName;
    private final List<CarModel> models;
    private boolean selected;

    public CarBrand(String brandName, List<CarModel> models) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
        this.models = models;
    }

    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }

    public List<CarModel> getModels() {
        return models;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Car Model:

```
public class CarModel {

    private final String modelName;
    private final int year;
    private boolean selected;

    public CarModel(String modelName, int year) {
        this.modelName = modelName;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getModelName() {
        return modelName;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

CDI Managed Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.primefaces.event.ToggleEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.Visibility;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    List<CarBrand> brands;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        brands = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CarModel> carModels;

        carModels = new ArrayList<>();
        carModels.add(new CarModel("CL 63 AMG", 2011, 1));
        carModels.add(new CarModel("S-Class Coupe", 2014, 2));
        carModels.add(new CarModel("AMG GTS", 2015, 3));
        brands.add(new CarBrand("Mercedes", carModels));

        carModels = new ArrayList<>();
        carModels.add(new CarModel("M5 F10", 2012, 4));
        carModels.add(new CarModel("M6 F13", 2012, 5));
        carModels.add(new CarModel("X5 M", 2015, 6));
        brands.add(new CarBrand("BMW", carModels));

        carModels = new ArrayList<>();
        carModels.add(new CarModel("Polo", 2012, 7));
        carModels.add(new CarModel("Golf GTI", 2013, 8));
        carModels.add(new CarModel("Golf R", 2015, 9));
        brands.add(new CarBrand("Volkswagen", carModels));
    }

    public void onRowToggle(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        ToggleEvent toggleEvent = (ToggleEvent) event;
        FacesMessage msg;
        if (toggleEvent.getVisibility() == Visibility.VISIBLE) {
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Toggled", "Visibility:" + toggleEvent.getVisibility());
        } else {
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Untoggled", "Visibility:" + toggleEvent.getVisibility());
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public List<CarBrand> getBrands() {
        return brands;
    }
}
```

and .xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="testForm" prependId="true">
            <p:growl id="growl"/>
            <p:dataTable id="carsTable" value="#{bean.brands}" var="brand" style="width: 400px">
                <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{bean.onRowToggle}" update="testForm:growl"/>
                <p:column style="width: 20px">
                    <p:rowToggler/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Brand">
                    <b><h:outputText value="#{brand.brandName}"/></b>
                </p:column>
                <p:rowExpansion>
                    <p:dataTable id="modelsTable" value="#{brand.models}" var="model">
                        <p:column headerText="Model">
                            <h:outputText value="#{model.modelName}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Year">
                            <h:outputText value="#{model.year}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width: 20px">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectAll" value="#{brand.selected}" rendered="#{not empty brand.models}">
                                    <p:ajax/>
                                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="modelSelect" value="#{model.selected}">
                                <p:ajax/>
                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:rowExpansion>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is even worse than you mention. It is caused by the implementation of the toggle. If you see what is going on in the DOM, the expanded items get removed completely. When you toggle it back, the object are re-rendered.

For some reason text values are preserved, but the checkboxes get reverted to their original value.

The situation is worth though. If you do not expand the expansion, then the not rendered elements are not submitted, which for checkboxes means their values are changed to "false" no matter what was their original value.

You have basically two options:

1. move checkboxes outside the expansion
2. store their value using Javascript outside their expanded area

Comment: Adding the issue link: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/942

Comment: Thanks, but I already keep their value in the object for which the checkbox is intended

Comment: I saw some activity in the Github issue this behavior relates. I hope PM team will fix it properly. The suggestions above are heavy and uncomfortable workaround.